# Factorization of linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question:

> Let $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ be complex Euclidean spaces and
>   let $A \in L(\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{X})$ be any non-zero operator.
>
> Prove that there exists a complex Euclidean space $\mathcal{Z}$ along
>   with vectors $u \in \mathcal{X} ⊗ \mathcal{Z}$ and $v \in \mathcal{Z}
>  ⊗ \mathcal{Y}$ such that $A = (\mathcal{I}_{\mathcal{X}} \otimes
> v^{*})~ (u \otimes \mathcal{I}_{\mathcal{Y}})$.
>
> What is the minimum possible dimension of $\mathcal{Z}$ that is
>   required to write a given $A$ in this way?

My attempt:

My intuition was to apply the singular value decomposition theorem and see where that leads me. The SVD theorem says

$A = \sum_{i=1}^{r} s_{i} x_{i} y_{i}^{*}$ where $r$ is the rank of the matrix and $\{x_{1}, x_{2}, \cdots x_{r} \}$ and $\{y_{1}, y_{2}, \cdots y_{r} \}$ are orthonormal sets of vectors belonging to $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ respectively.

Perhaps there is some way to use these vectors to construct $v$ and $u$ but I am completely lost at this point. Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: what are the non-rendering symbols (I see them as question marks on the left of the $u\otimes\mathcal I_{\mathcal Y}$) supposed to represent?

Comment: Edited them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $u\equiv \sum_k \sqrt{s_k} x_k\otimes e_k\in\mathcal X\otimes\mathcal Z$, where $e_k$ are an orthonormal basis for $\mathcal Z$.

Define $v\equiv \sum_k \sqrt{s_k} e_k\otimes y_k\in\mathcal Z\otimes\mathcal Y$.

Then, you have
$$(I_{\mathcal X}\otimes v^*)(u \otimes I_{\mathcal Y})
=\sum_{jk}\sqrt{s_j s_k}
(I_{\mathcal X}\otimes e_j^*\otimes y_j^*)
(x_k\otimes e_k\otimes I_{\mathcal Y})
=\sum_k s_k x_k\otimes y_k^*,
$$
which is $A$ thought of as an element of $\mathcal X\otimes\mathcal Y^*$.

To define $u,v$ you need a number of $e_k$ elements equal to the number of nonvanishing singular values $s_k$, which equals the rank of $A$, and thus $\dim\mathcal Z=\operatorname{rank}(A)$ is enough to accommodate this number of orthonormal vectors and write the matrix in this form.

Comment: Thanks! What is the minimum dimension of $\mathcal{Z}$ for which this holds? My intuition is that it equals the rank of the matrix. How do we show that?